# Select custom file in a file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, file-upload

I want to use `Choose File` to select a file in a file upload. CAn anyone help me fix this using Javascript, Jquery, CSS, or some other method?

Comment: any effort from your end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out: [Bootstrap fileStyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/)

You first need to import `js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"> </script>
```

and then change the button text using:

JavaScript:

```
$(":file").filestyle({buttonText: "Select file"});
```

OR through simple HTML:

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Select file">
```